# facebook integration suddenly failed using this php class

Tags: php, facebook, class

Facebook integration has been working perfectly on my site for some time, then overnight something happened at facebook because it's now failing.

Can someone have a look at the code I use all over my site and advise what I should do to get this working again as soon as possible, without having to remodel the whole implementation?

```
<?php
// http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

class Facebook_class
{

var $cookie;

function Facebook_class() {
    $this->cookie = $this->get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
}

function getUserid() {
    $cookie = $this->getCookie();
    $fb_userid = $cookie['uid'];
    return $fb_userid;
}

function getProfilePicture() {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->getUserid().'/picture?type=large';
    //$url = 'api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT pic_big FROM user WHERE uid = '.$this->getUserid();
    $url = $this->get_redirect_url($url);
    return $url;
}

function getUserData() {
    if($this->getCookie()) {
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
        $userData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        return $userData;
    }
}

function getCookie() {
    return $this->cookie;
}

function getAccessToken() {
    return $this->cookie['access_token'];
}

function loadJsSDK($path_to_library='') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[ ';

    ?>
    function logoutFacebookUser(){FB.logout(function(response){window.location.reload();});}
    function fbActionConnect(){FB.login(function(response){if (response.session){window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/signin/fbconnect";if(response.perms){}else{}}else{}}, {perms:'publish_stream,email'});}
    function fbAppActionConnect(){FB.login(function(response){if (response.session){window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/signin/fbappconnect";if(response.perms){}else{}}else{}}, {perms:'publish_stream,email'});}
    function fbLinkActionConnect(){FB.login(function(response){if (response.session){window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?name=signin&file=MyServices&op=linkacc";if(response.perms){}else {}}else{}},{perms:'publish_stream,email'});}
    function fbActionCartConnect(id, sport) {FB.login(function(response){if(response.session){window.location = "//index.php?name=signin&file=cart&id=" + id + "&sport=" + sport + "&op=fbsignup";if (response.perms){}else{}}else{}},{perms:'publish_stream,email'});}
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({appId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, channelUrl:'http://www.mysite.com/channel.html', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});};(function() {var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());//]]></script>
    <?php
}

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

function get_redirect_url($url) {
    $redirect_url = null; 

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getFacebookFriends($criteria='') {
    $name = $criteria['name'];

    if($name=='') $name = 'me';

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$name.'/friends?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
    $content = @file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
    $content = json_decode($content,true);

    $users = $this->formatFacebookUsers($content);

    return $users;
}

function formatFacebookUsers($content) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($content['data']); $i++) {
        $id = $content['data'][$i]['id'];
        $name = $content['data'][$i]['name'];

        $picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?type=square'; //square, small, large
        $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$id;

        $users[$i]['id'] = $id;
        $users[$i]['name'] = $name;
        $users[$i]['picture'] = $picture;
        $users[$i]['url'] = $url;
    }
    return $users;
}

function getFacebookAccounts() {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
    $content = @file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
    $content = json_decode($content,true);
    return $content;
}

function displayUsersIcons($criteria) {
    $users = $criteria['users'];
    $nb_display = $criteria['nb_display'];
    $width = $criteria['width'];

    if($width=='') $width="30";

    if($nb_display>count($users) || $nb_display=='') $nb_display=count($users); //display value never bigger than nb users

    $display = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$nb_display;$i++) {
        $name = $users[$i]['name'];
        $picture = $users[$i]['picture'];
        $url = $users[$i]['url'];

        $display .= '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" title="'.$name.'">';
        $display .= '<img src="'.$picture.'" width="'.$width.'" style="padding:2px;">';
        $display .= '</a>';
    }
    return $display;
}

function getFacebookFeeds() {

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($data,true);
    $dataList = $this->formatFacebookPosts($data);

    return $dataList;
}

function formatFacebookPosts($data) {
    $i=0;
    foreach($data['data'] as $value) {
        $id = $value['id'];
        $from_id = $value['from']['id'];
        $from_name = $value['from']['name'];

        $type = $value['type']; //video, link, status, picture, swf
        $message = $value['message'];
        $picture = $value['picture'];
        $link = $value['link'];
        $source = $value['source']; //for videos
        $name = $value['name']; //for videos or links
        $caption = $value['caption']; //for videos (domain name url) or links
        $description = $value['description']; //for videos
        $icon = $value['icon'];
        $created = $value['created_time'];
        $likes_nb = $value['likes'];

        $comments = $value['comments']['data']; //(message, created_time)
        $comments_nb = $value['comments']['count'];
        $action_comment = $value['actions'][0]['link'];

        $picture_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$from_id.'/picture';
        $profile_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$from_id;

        $attribution = $value['attribution'];

        if($type=='status') {
            $dataList[$i]['id'] = $id;
            $dataList[$i]['from_id'] = $from_id;
            $dataList[$i]['from_name'] = $from_name;
            $dataList[$i]['type'] = $type;
            $dataList[$i]['message'] = $message;
            $dataList[$i]['picture'] = $picture;
            $dataList[$i]['link'] = $link;
            $dataList[$i]['source'] = $source;
            $dataList[$i]['name'] = $name;
            $dataList[$i]['caption'] = $caption;
            $dataList[$i]['description'] = $description;
            $dataList[$i]['icon'] = $icon;
            $dataList[$i]['created'] = $created;
            $dataList[$i]['attribution'] = $attribution;
            $dataList[$i]['likes_nb'] = $likes_nb;
            $dataList[$i]['comments'] = $comments;
            $dataList[$i]['comments_nb'] = $comments_nb;
            $dataList[$i]['action_comment'] = $action_comment;
            $dataList[$i]['picture_url'] = $picture_url;
            $dataList[$i]['profile_url'] = $profile_url;
            $i++;   
        }
    }
    return $dataList;
}

function updateFacebookStatus($status) {
    $postParms = "access_token=".$this->getAccessToken()."&message=".$status;
    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParms);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function postmsg() {
    $FILE_PATH = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."images/default/webedition1.jpg";
    $token=$this->getAccessToken();

    if (file_exists($FILE_PATH)) { 

       $args = array('message' => 'From the coaches locker');
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);


    $arr_attachment = array('image' => '@'.realpath($FILE_PATH),
                            'message' => 'Test caption'
                        );
    $_curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=".$token);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr_attachment);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $_photo = curl_exec($_curl);
    echo($_photo);

    } else {
    echo "cannot find file:".$FILE_PATH;
    }
}


}

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: need to know the error you're seeing.  at the very least, what you expect, and what you're getting.

Comment: sure, overnight the fbActionConnect() function stopped popping up the facebook login window.  So nobody can now signup or authenticate to my site anymore.  this was all working fine, and without any code changes it's just stopped working overnight.

Comment: `fbActionConnect` appears to be JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: aye, i it is.  the loadJsSDK php function calls it.

Comment: have you verified that facebook didn't make / push any changes that would break it?

Comment: am looking now.  i suspect facebook have changed something to stop it working.  still hunting however.  what i've found so far which is similar is suggesting "perms:'publish_stream,email'" should be changed to "scope:'publish_stream,email'" which i've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook introduced some breaking changes for OAuth2 authentication to the JavaScript SDK yesterday: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/614/

More details: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Basically some changes I've seen were:

1. FB.getSession() now changed to FB.getAuthResponse()
2. FB.init() now has the 'oath' value as always 'true'.
3. 'perms' is now changed to 'scope' in the login button html
4. Possibly FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange'..) is now FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange'..)

Hope that helps.

Comment: does this mean i have to completely remodel my site to suit facebook?

Comment: I only use the Facebook JavaScript SDK through Google Web Toolkit (not PHP), so I don't know how much work it'll take to make the changes. You'll probably have to change code though. Start with the loadJsSDK() function where you have the javascript code.